# Memory management and speed in for-loops

Tags: java, performance, loops, memory

I've just read that in a text-book, so I wanted to know if that's actually true.

Let's say, we have an array with some values in it that we want to iterate through:

---

```
for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
     //some code
}
```

---

Now every time it jumps back to the beginning of the loop it has to re-calculate the length of the array. Therefore, the book suggests, it would be better practice to create an integer of that length and compare x with that integer instead of the array-length.

---

```
for(int x = 0, int length = array.length; x < length; x++) {
     //some code
}
```

---

So from my understandings the first version is appearently slower but saves memory, whereas in the second version we use a little more space to make it faster. But I've never seen the second version in practice, so I wanted to know what code would be better to use.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the one that's more readable (the first one) until you can show that performance has become an issue in your application. And as @Jason said, arrays store the length as a public (non-calculated) field.

Comment: If that book is about *Java*, you need to throw it away immediately. Conditional on it being about Java, I have enough information to conclude that it's a terrible book.

Comment: @Jason Oh man, 30$ wasted for nothing. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Now every time it jumps back to the beginning of the loop it has to re-calculate the length of the array.

Completely untrue. Array lengths are stored as part of the array in Java.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7):

> The members of an array type are all of the following:
>
> - **The public final field `length`, which contains the number of components of the array**. length may be positive or zero.
> - The public method `clone`, which overrides the method of the same name in class `Object` and throws no checked exceptions. The return type of the `clone` method of an array type `T[]` is `T[]`.
>
>   A clone of a multidimensional array is shallow, which is to say that it creates only a single new array. Subarrays are shared.
> - All the members inherited from class `Object`; the only method of `Object` that is not inherited is its `clone` method.

Also:

> Therefore, the book suggests, it would be better practice to create an integer of that length and compare `x` with that integer instead of the array-length.

Is this a *Java*-centric book? If so, throw it away immediately and get a new book. Getting something this fundamental wrong is a *terrible* signal about the quality of the book.

Comment: If you were to iterate over a `List` using a regular for-loop with `size()` and `get(index)`, it *may* help. Although, I can't come up with an example `List` implementation which has an expensive `size()` (which may benefit from caching) and an inexpensive `get(index)`. Either way, you'd probably be better off using an `ListIterator` anyhow.